# Non-Locality of Space - QFT (Srednicki's book)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, klein-gordon-equation, non-locality

I was going through Mark Srednicki's book on QFT. It says in the relativistic limit the Schrodinger equation becomes something like  :

$$ i\hbar\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \psi(\vec x,t) = \sqrt{-\hbar^2c^2\nabla^2+m^2c^4}\psi(\vec x,t) $$
Now he says that if I expand the square root (say binomially) it will have infinite no. of spatial derivatives acting on $\psi(x,t)$; this implies that
equation is not local in space.

What exactly does it mean to say the equation is not local in space?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/13624/ or more directly http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/18762/, but this approaches from a different enough angle that I'm not personally inclined to close.

Comment: Is there something you're wondering about that is not covered in Grumiller's answer to the question in the first link?

Comment: I am just not very sure how it works in a more general manner. Say you don't consider the discretisation scheme to look at what is happening !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you consider a standard differential operator $B$ working on functions defined in $\mathbb R^n$, like $\partial/\partial x_i$ or a polynomial of partial derivatives, and pick out a sufficiently smooth function $f$ vanishing in a neighbourhood $\Omega$, you see that also $Bf$ vanishes therein. This is the relevant notion of **locality** for operators.

In the  RHS of the equation you wrote down  an operator shows up which does not fulfil locality in the sense I said.
That equation is, in fact, the equation satisfied by the positive energy solutions of Klein-Gordon equation.

The operator in the RHS cannot be defined by formal Taylor expansion (it works only formally), but one has to use spectral theory. In the considered case it is equivalent to translate that equation in Fourier transform.

Non locality arises here due to a known property of the operator $A:= \sqrt{-\Delta + aI}$ and, more generally, for $(\Delta + aI)^\nu$ with $\nu \not \in \mathbb Z$. This property is called **anti locality** (I.E. Segal, R.W. Goodman, J. Math. Mech. 14 (1965) 629) and is  related to the famous **Reeh and Schlieder property** in QFT.

Anti locality means that If both $f$ and $Af$ vanish in a bounded  region $\Omega \subset \mathbb R^3$ then $f$ is **everywhere** zero.

If $f$ has support included in a bounded open set $\Omega$, then, **remarkably** 
and **very differently from what happens for standard differential operators**, $Af$ **does not identically vanish** outside $\Omega$ otherwise $f$ would be the everywhere zero function.